# I need to display a value as well as the Name of its Origin Host in PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I work on a script to get values needed for a checkup of vCenter properties and data, automaticaly via PowerShell script.

At the moment I am at a point where I want to get the average memory usage of all hosts in % as realtime value from the last entry, so you as user you can see all averages and can check them like: if one host would die would the other or one other be capable of replacing him without getting over 100% mem usage.

That's the easy part I use:

```
Get-Vm |
    Get-Stat -Stat mem.usage.average -Realtime -MaxSamples 1 |
    select Value,Unit
```

and the output is

```
Value Unit
----
0,99 %
0,99 %
```

My desired output would look like this

```
Name Value Unit
----- - ----
Test1 0,99 %
Test2 0,99 %
```

I tried to include

```
Get-Vm | select Name
```

which gives me exactly the missing part of my desired output, but I am not so sure how I could include it to be like the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Stat`provides you the `Entity`. So you could use:

```
Get-Vm |
    Get-Stat -Stat mem.usage.average -Realtime -MaxSamples 1 |
    select Entity, Value,Unit
```